# Background image in home page is not working?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

The background image is not working while I set the option to 100%.

[image: That's what i got as a result]

I'm using angular and bootstrap 4.

```
<!--html code-->
<div class="bg">
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is the .scss code

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("~/assets/jonatan-pie-226805-unsplash.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code and added a picture and it works below.

Are you using anything that would implicitly keep the background small? Maybe a bootstrap?

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://www.placecage.com/g/1000/500");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--html code-->
<div class="bg">
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Works fine for me isn't an answer. At best it's a comment.